# C++ - Makefile issues

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm writing a small program known as "Alert Center", and the main classes/objects I'm using are: Point, Line, and Building. The contents of my Makefile are:

```
building.o: building.h line.h point.h building.cpp
    g++ -c building.cpp
line.o: line.h point.h line.cpp
    g++ -c line.cpp
point.o: point.h point.cpp
    g++ -c point.cpp
alert_center: point.o line.o building.o
    g++ point.o line.o building.o runner.cpp -o alert_center
```

The problem is that it only considers the first file listed. For example, if I change `line.cpp`, and then run `make`, nothing will happen and it will say that `building.o` has not changed. The change will only be compiled if I make the rule for `line.o` the first one. Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: You need `make alert_center`. Just typing `make` makes the *first* target. (Alternatively, move the `alert_center` target to the top of the makefile.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `alert_center` the default target.  You can do that explicitly with `.default` (see [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Targets)), or simply list it as the first target to make it the default.

In the case of multiple targets, it is common to have a pseudo target named `all` and have it be the default.  See the make recommended targets [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Standard-Targets).